# Security in firebase/firestore

Tags: firebase, authentication, google-cloud-firestore, api-key

In a project I'm currently working on I'm using cloud FireStore and underlying DB.

I need my client (iOS and Android) to be able to read (no wrtie access at all) documents from cloud FireStore regardless of the user is logged in or not (actually not going to use firebase auth at all).

I do not want anyone to be able to access the data from outside the apps (thru the REST endpoints for example).
I guess what I need is to bake in some sort of API-key into the app that grants the access, but I do not see how I can do this, can anyone guide me in the right direction?

Comment: Hmm just asking. If its an app, why not log them in?

Comment: Well the content simply should not require the user to log in. Not all users would want to log in. However when the user actually logs in they do it thru our own OAuth solution, which of cause could be hooked up to firebase auth if we wanted but I'm trying to avoid this..

Comment: hmm ok. That just sounds strange to my ears, that the users should not log in - but the data should still not be public available?

Comment: I get that, it's simply because I don't want the data to be accessible from outside the app...

Comment: I actually like your idea - change security based on the location. Its similar to protecting based on IP address. I will try to help you investigate if this is possible, but I have a feeling that we need to create a feature request for the firebase team.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know you say you don't want to use Firebase Auth, but I think signing in anonymously is the way to go. This will allow them to receive a uid without signing up/logging in so you can validate them in your Firebase/Firestore security rules. The web version looks something like this, but its implemented for Android/IOS as well. This code is taken directly from [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/anonymous-auth).

```
firebase.auth().signInAnonymously().catch(function(error) {
  // Handle Errors here.
  var errorCode = error.code;
  var errorMessage = error.message;
  // ...
});

firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  if (user) {
    // User is signed in.
    var isAnonymous = user.isAnonymous;
    var uid = user.uid;
    // ...
  } else {
    // User is signed out.
    // ...
  }
  // ...
});
```

[IOS version](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/anonymous-auth)
[Android version](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/anonymous-auth)

Comment: You might just be right. This does seem like the way to go... but will this prevent users from generating an anonymous id thru the REST API and accessing the data that way? I need to prevent our data from leaking thru the rest API...

Comment: Ultimately this data is public to anyone since they can get it just by being in your app. The odds of someone outside of the app grabbing your data is possible, but the likelihood is low. If you really need bank level security, you should think about having them sign up with a real account. But how many apps need bank level security?